# QField - Updated existing point in geopackage coordinates (X,Y,Z) based on my location

Tags: qgis, qfield

I've been using QField for a while now specially for big surveys >1000 points.

It works great and I've managed to make it use my location coordinates (provided by the device running QField) to auto populate X,Y,Z coordinates when creating NEW POINTS.

What I would like it to do is to populate the X,Y,Z in a pre uploaded Geopackage with a planned sampling grid.

The procedure on QField that I am trying to have is:

- Give the teams QField projects with a predefined sampling grid.
- Team gets to the one point and starts editing the pre-existing point of the preexisting geopackage layer in QField
- QField automatically get's the X,Y,Z from current position and populates those fields automatically

Is this possible ?

Comment: In QGIS you need to configure the Default value option for these fields, in order to allow their values to be updated.

Comment: Can you please guide me through that ?
I've done that for newly created points. Don't know the code to put for points to edit

Comment: In QGIS, you need to open layer properties of that pre-existing points. At **Attributes Form**, select your field. In the settings on the right, scroll down to the bottom and activate the option **Apply default value on update**